# PWA: prevent urls from opening in the PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, window.open, angular-pwa

I've built an angular app using `@angular/pwa`, that supports external logins like Microsoft, Google, Facebook and Twiitter. When a user wants to signin using an external login, I'm using `window.open` to open the url hosting the `Challenge`.

The problem is that when calling `window.open` from the web app in the browser, the url is being forced to open in the PWA.

I've litterally already tried everything I can to prevent this, but without success. The last thing I've tried was to [host my endpoints for my external logins on a subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554479/pwa-force-window-open-to-open-browser-instead-of-pwa), which worked quite well.

But now I've implemented 2FA in my web app, and for 2FA to work, the `ExternalLoginSigninAsync` must be called from the same domain as the call to `TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync`. So how can I force an url (window.open) to open in the browser instead of the PWA?

PS: Don't come up with

1. Exclude from navigationUrls (`"navigationUrls": [ "!/web/v3/Account/connect/" ]`)
2. `window.open(url, '_system')`
3. `window.open(url, '_blank')`
4. Use ngsw-bypass (`window.open(url + '?ngsw-bypass=true')`)

That's all been tried, and doesn't work.

### Edit

[This block of code](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/webapps/WebappLauncherActivity.java#L214) appears to determine whether the PWA should be launched or a new tab should be opened.

Call stack:

- [WebappLauncherActivity.shouldLaunchWebapp](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/webapps/WebappLauncherActivity.java#L214)
- [WebApkValidator.canWebApkHandleUrl](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/components/webapk/android/libs/client/src/org/chromium/components/webapk/lib/client/WebApkValidator.java#L120)
- [WebApkValidator.resolveInfosForUrlAndOptionalPackage](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/components/webapk/android/libs/client/src/org/chromium/components/webapk/lib/client/WebApkValidator.java#L149) should return `false` for the urls you don't want opened in the PWA

Comment: `<a target=_blank>`?

Comment: I already tried that. Still opens in the PWA

Comment: Anyone interested, upvote the [following issue](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/989)